# How to plot a region defined by corner points

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

As we know,`t1*p1 + t2*p2 + t3*p3` is a triangle region whose vertice is `{p1,p2,p3}` when `t1+t2+t3==1` and `0<t1<1&&0<t2<1&&0<t3<1`.But I don't know how to draw this triangle?I just can estimate it with some points like

```
SeedRandom[2]
{p1, p2, p3} = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
t = Normalize[#, Total] & /@ RandomReal[1, {400, 3}];
Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], 
  Point[Dot @@@ Tuples[{t, {{p1, p2, p3}}}]], Red, 
  Point[{p1, p2, p3}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But how to plot it **with a shape**?If I use `ParametricRegion`,it will be a parallelogram

```
Region@ParametricRegion[
   t1*p1 + t2*p2 + (1 - t1 - t2)*p3, {{t1, 0, 1}, {t2, 0, 1}}]~Show~
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Point /@ {p1, p2, p3}}]
```

How to implement it?

Comment: You need `RegionFunction` for plotting in barycentric coordinates: `ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 1 - u - v}.{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, u + v <= 1]]`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks,I think it deseve an answer,and I will open it to wait other solution.

Comment: Why not just `Region[Simplex[{p1,p2,p3}]`?

Comment: @kglr Fun,I just guess that `t1+t2+t3==1`  is a triangle,and want to plot it to comfirm.If I change it into `t1+t2+t3==2`,you cannot use `Simplex` anymore. :)

Comment: Or `Graphics3D[Polygon[{p1,p2,p3,p1}]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
reg[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 1 - u - v}.{p1, p2, p3}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 
    0, 1 - u}, Mesh -> None], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{p1, p2, p3}]}]]
```

e.g.

```
Grid[Partition[reg @@@ RandomInteger[10, {9, 3, 3}], 3]]
```

[image]

David G. Stork (in the comments) points out: `Polygon[{p1,p2,p3}]` or `Triangle[{p1,p2,p3}`are simpler options.